# What do the dollar signs in the location screen mean?

Tags: caves-of-qud

What does the green/gray dollar sign next to each location mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> [You can only share each secret once. Once you do, it's out in the world.](https://steamcommunity.com/games/333640/announcements/detail/1291815558676794628)

I think a gray dollar sign indicates that the location is not secret anymore.